# #error add -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS-64 to your compile flags

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-14.04, fuse

When I compile a hello.c program that contain a fuse.h header file it shows this error. - #error add -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS-64 to your compile flags. while accessing fuse_common.h.
Previously, I have installed fuse filesystem from fuse.sourceforge.net and run an example from that fuse-2.9.3. Could anyone know how to fix this error. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - i386 (32 bit) on VM of oracle.

Answer (score 5):

Try to modify the `Makefile` to add a line:

```
CFLAGS += -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

Alternately, you can add a line in `hello.c` before you include `fuse.h`:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS  64
#include <fuse.h>
```